# A Timer has a chan field named C. To return it, must I suffix it with parentheses?

Tags: go, syntax

I'm a Go rookie.

I'm looking at some [Kubernetes source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/tools/cache/reflector.go#L233) that looks in part like this:

```
t := r.clock.NewTimer(r.resyncPeriod)
return t.C(), t.Stop
```

`t` is a [new `Timer`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer), and I can see that the `Timer` type has a field named `C`, which is a `chan` whose messages, should there be any, will be of type [`Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time).  I understand that part.

I don't understand why it's `t.C()` above, and not `t.C` (no parentheses).  To my naïve eyes, this looks like some sort of function invocation on the channel.  Could someone kindly explain what's going on here?  What do the parentheses indicate, in particular?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [Clock](https://github.com/kubernetes/metrics/blob/master/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/clock/clock.go#L26)

you will find:

```
type Clock interface {
    Now() time.Time
    Since(time.Time) time.Duration
    After(d time.Duration) <-chan time.Time
    NewTimer(d time.Duration) Timer
    Sleep(d time.Duration)
    Tick(d time.Duration) <-chan time.Time
}
```

Notice that clock's NewTimer returns a [Timer](https://github.com/kubernetes/metrics/blob/master/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/clock/clock.go#L255) from k8s `clock` package, which is defined as:

```
type Timer interface {
    C() <-chan time.Time
    Stop() bool
    Reset(d time.Duration) bool
}
```

And that's what you are calling to get the channel.

This is so they can swap out the timer, likely for test cases.

So, while it looks like the stdlib's [Timer](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer) type, it's really an interface to allow swapability.